# scrapy spider stops at the first duplicated item

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am using scrapy 0.20 with python 2.7

I want to avoid duplicated items.

I want to not use the `JOBDIR` as parameter in the command line. Instead, I am doing this in my script:

```
settings.overrides['JOBDIR']= 'my customer jobdir'
```

Then I do this in my settings:

```
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'MyProject.CustomFilter.CustomFilter'
```

and in the `CustomFilter` I am suing this:

```
def request_seen(self, request):
        fp = self.__getid(request.url)
        if (fp is not None) and (fp in self.fingerprints):
            return True
        elif fp is not None:
            self.fingerprints.add(fp)
            if self.file:
                self.file.write(fp + os.linesep)
        else:
            return False
```

where `__getid` is a helper function I used.

#### my problem

the spider stops working when it finds the first duplicated item.

and I found this message on the CMD:

```
2014-03-03 10:43:44-0800 [GeneralSpider] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET
 http://www.justproperty.com/apartments/old-town/1057362-most-affordable-2-b-r-i
n-old-town-for-sale.html> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_CLA
SS)
```

Comment: In your spider, are you yielding the above URL - `http://www.justproperty.com/apartments/old-town/1057362-most-affordable-2-b-r-i
n-old-town-for-sale.html` as a request?

Comment: @warunsl actually, I have many pages, each page have many items. each item has a link. i am scraping over these items' links. Thus, that url, which you provide, is one of the links that I extract when scraping the master page and then I yield on it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parameter `dont_filter=True` on your Request call. This will direct scrapy to not ignore duplicate requests. It is documented [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request)

Comment: This doesn't help me at all. I do want to not scrap the duplicated items. but I have a problem which is the spider stops working after finding the first dubplicated item.

Answer (score 1):

Enable DUPEFILTER_DEBUG = True in settings.py

Now duplicate filter in the scheduler filters out all URLs already seen in a single spider run (meaning that it will get reset on subsequent runs).

If you want to continue crawling,ignoring duplicate URLs.
The IgnoreVistedItems middleware keeps a state between runs and avoiding visiting URLs seen in the past, but only for final item URLs so that the rest of the site can be re-crawled (in order to find new items).
Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

According to me you should check item return logic in spider. I was facing same issue.